# Pandas drop all cells with Values and leave only blank cells

Tags: python, pandas, drop

I want to do the following:

| index | A1 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | -8 |
| 3 | Hello |
| 4 |  |

to:

| index | A1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 4 |  |

Is there like a reverse .dropna function?

Comment: The input is ambiguous, are your `---` NaNs? empty strings? It would be preferable to provide a dictionary as input (`df.to_dict()`)

Comment: yes they shall be real NaNs

Comment: OK, then try the first option in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming real NaNs:

```
out = df[df['A1'].isna()]
```

If empty strings:

```
out = df[df['A1'].eq('')]
```

For both:

```
out = df[df['A1'].fillna('').eq('')]
```